# Python: 'int' not subscriptable

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

Here is my code to read in a file. I am supposed to sort the numbers in columns[14] in descending order.

My code is giving me the error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

How can I fix this?

```
with open("AT.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split("\t")
        if (int(columns[14]) > 0):
            array = [columns[1], int(columns[14])]
            sorted(array, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

For example when I output print(array) before the sorted line I have:

```
    ['Bartenberg', 50]
    ['Eden', 66]
    ['Watzing', 23]
```

My desired output would be:

```
    ['Watzing', 23]
    ['Bartenberg', 50]
    ['Eden', 66]
```

If I change my code to something like:

```
with open("AT.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split("\t")
        if (int(columns[14]) > 0):
            c15 = int(columns[14])
            array = [columns[1], c15]
            sorted(array, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
            print(array)
```

I still get the same error

When I put my data in a dictionary:

```
dictlist =[dict[columns[7], columns[14]]]
```

I get the same error

Comment: Please show example data and desired output.

Comment: second element in the array is `int`, so while sorting, the key function tries to index the int object.

Comment: But if I get rid of the int the numbers won't be sorted. What do I do?

Comment: Try: Lambda x: str(x)[1]

Comment: Now it gives me IndexError: string index out of range